# How do I do a one way diff in Linux?

Tags: linux, file, command, diff, difference

How do I do a one way diff in Linux?

**Normal behavior of diff:**

Normally, diff will tell you all the differences between a two files.  For example, it will tell you anything that is in file A that is not in file B, and will also tell you everything that is in file B, but not in file A.  For example:

**File A contains:**

```
cat
good dog
one
two
```

**File B contains:**

```
cat
some garbage
one
a whole bunch of garbage
something I don't want to know
```

If I do a regular diff as follows:

> diff A B

the output would be something like:

```
2c2
< good dog
---
> some garbage
4c4,5
< two
---
> a whole bunch of garbage
> something I don't want to know
```

**What I am looking for:**

What I want is just the first part, for example, I want to know everything that is in File A, but not file B.  However, I want it to ignore everything that is in file B, but not in file A.

**What I want is the command, or series of commands:**

**???? A B**

that produces the output:

```
2c2
< good dog
4c4,5
< two
```

I believe a solution could be achieved by piping the output of diff into sed or awk, but I am not familiar enough with those tools to come up with a solution.  I basically want to remove all lines that begin with --- and >.

Edit: I edited the example to account for multiple words on a line.

Note: This is a "sub-question" of: [Determine list of non-OS packages installed on a RedHat Linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319561/determine-list-of-non-os-packages-installed-on-a-redhat-linux-machine)

Note: This is similar to, but not the same as the question asked here (e.g. not a dupe): 
[One-way diff file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669413/one-way-diff-file)

Comment: This feels like a superuser question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`diff A B|grep '^<'|awk '{print $2}'`

`grep '^<'` means select rows start with <

`awk '{print $2}'` means select the second column

Comment: Thank you so much, that put me on the right track.  The problem with print $2 is that it ignores any words that come later (e.g. if I put "good dog" in file A vs. dog.  It turns out that the first part of the command achieves what I want though, e.g. the following command: diff A B | grep '^<'

Comment: @Jonathan try this: diff A B|grep '^<'|cut -c 3-

Answer (score 10):

An alternative, if your files consist of single-line entities only, and the output order doesn't matter (the question as worded is unclear on this), would be:

```
comm -23 <(sort A) <(sort B)
```

`comm` requires its inputs to be sorted, and the `-2` means "don't show me the lines that are unique to the second file", while `-3` means "don't show me the lines that are common between the two files".

If you need the "differences" to be presented in the order they occur, though, the above `diff` / `awk` solution is ok (although the `grep` bit isn't really necessary - it could be `diff A B | awk '/^</ { $1 = ""; print }'`.

EDIT: fixed which set of lines to report - I read it backwards originally...

Answer (score 8):

As stated in the comments, one mostly correct answer is

```
diff A B | grep '^<'
```

although this would give the output

```
< good dog
< two
```

rather than

```
2c2
< good dog
4c4,5
< two
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to also see the files in question, in case of diffing folders, you can use

```
diff public_html temp_public_html/ | grep '^[^>]'
```

to match all but lines starting with >