# What Git command will display content present only in a branch whose commits have been fully merged to master?

Tags: git, merge, git-diff

What [Git](http://www.git-scm.com/) commands will display content present only in a branch whose commits have been fully merged to `master`?  Some content may be missing from `master` because, for example some merge operations may have used the `ours` strategy, ignoring the branch content (i.e. `git merge --strategy ours branch`).

I have found that the usual [Git comparison operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834689/comparing-two-branches-in-git) do not produce the result that I desire.

For example, commands `git diff master..branch` and `git diff branch..master` do not work because these show content differences present in `master`.  (How can I modify this command to omit the changes on `master`?)

Command `git diff master...branch` also does not work because all commits on `branch` have previously been merged to master in multiple merge operations over time.

Example:

1. Create file `a.txt` in branch `master`.
2. Add line 1 to `a.txt` in branch `master`.
3. Create branch `branch`.
4. Add line 2 to `a.txt` in branch `branch`.
5. Switch to branch `master`.
6. Add line 2 to `a.txt` in branch `master`.
7. Merge branch `branch` to `master` using strategy `ours`. This is like a "dummy" merge which merges all commits on `branch` to `master`, but discards their content.
8. Compare branches `master` and `branch`.

Command sequence:

```
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects$ git init test
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/derek/Projects/test/.git/
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects$ cd test
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ touch a.txt
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ git add a.txt
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ git commit --message "Added a.txt."
[master (root-commit) 6a36816] Added a.txt.
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a.txt
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ echo "Line 1 from master." >> a.txt
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ git commit -a --message "Added line 1."
[master c9ebf16] Added line 1.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ git checkout -b branch
Switched to a new branch 'branch'
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ echo "Line 2 from branch." >> a.txt
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ git commit -a --message "Added line 2."
[branch 8a142dd] Added line 2.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ cat a.txt
Line 1 from master.
Line 2 from branch.
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ echo "Line 2 from master." >> a.txt
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ git commit -a --message "Added line 2."
[master d496cc7] Added line 2.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ git merge --strategy ours branch
Merge made by the 'ours' strategy.
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ git merge branch
Already up-to-date.
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ git diff master..branch
diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
index f773e76..5dae91a 100644
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 Line 1 from master.
-Line 2 from master.
+Line 2 from branch.
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ git diff branch..master
diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
index 5dae91a..f773e76 100644
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 Line 1 from master.
-Line 2 from branch.
+Line 2 from master.
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ git diff master...branch
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ git diff branch...master
diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
index 5dae91a..f773e76 100644
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 Line 1 from master.
-Line 2 from branch.
+Line 2 from master.
```

What Git operation can I use to show only "+Line 2 from branch." while ignoring "+Line 2 from master." or "-Line 2 from master."?

Comment: Have you tried `git diff master branch`?

Comment: Isn't this identical to `git diff master..branch`?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, I just simulated a conflict and solve it in the master. Then I execute this command and got difference in master: I have some content and in the other branch I have different content.

Comment: @zaratustra I think OP wants the command to ignore additions to `master` that are not in `branch`. `git diff master branch` would show additions/deletions both ways (and idk of any diff tool that wouldn't end up doing that).

Comment: @zaratustra, I added an an example to my question to illustrate my problem.

Comment: @SnoringFrog, yes, you correctly understand my problem.

Comment: This would be useful, for example, to tell you which changes in a branch may be absent from `master` even after having merged all of the commits on the branch to `master`.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing from [How do I do a one way diff in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390095/how-do-i-do-a-one-way-diff-in-linux):

You can pipe the output off the diff to `grep` to sort out the changes present in master. Best way I know to do that is to ignore any line that starts with a hyphen.

`git diff master branch | grep -v "^-"`

For me this showed the following output after following your steps:

> diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
>
> index f908dc1..1b5b3bd 100644
>
> +++ b/a.txt
>
> @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
>
> this line in both files
>
> +line2 on branch

whereas `git diff master branch` shows

> diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
>
> index f908dc1..1b5b3bd 100644
>
> --- a/a.txt
>
> +++ b/a.txt
>
> @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
>
> this line in both files
>
> -line2 in master
>
> +line2 on branch

This has the side effect of stripping the color from the diff and printing it out directly to stdout instead of to `less`. Since the color is there to help differentiate which file each listed change is in, it should not be necessary in one files changes removed. If you need to keep things displayed in `less`, simply add a pipe to `less` to the end of the command.

Edit: As @DerekMahar pointed out in his comment, this only shows you *additions* on `branch` that are not reflected in `master`. I'm not sure how to modify this to include all changes from `branch`, as I know no simple way to differentiate between an addition to `master` and a subtraction from `branch` while viewing a diff.

---

**The below is a very rough idea that, as explained here, would not fully solve the problem, but it feels like enough of a start I thought I should note it in case someone else knows how to work around the issues with it:**

My best initial thought (which requires more scripting than I have time for right now, and also has it's own collection of issues, but I figured I'd put it out here in case someone else can work with it) is to take the output of `git diff master branch | grep "^-"` (notice the lack of `-v`), and then search for the lines of that output in the proper file in `branch` (the filename would be available in the first line of output). We would then know any lines found in `branch` were *removed* from `master`, while any lines not found were *added* to `master`. However, lines that may be repeated (e.g., `{` by itself) would quickly cause problems with this method, and I'm not sure how to resolve that issue.

Comment: This may work for the simple example that I gave, but in another scenario, it also has the side effect of omitting lines that `branch` may have deleted.  It also doesn't ignore files that were added only to `master`.

Comment: @DerekMahar In that case I think you're out of luck, as there's no way to differentiate between "deleted from `branch`" and "added to `master`" (even when looking at a normal diff, as far as I can tell. Much less on a one-way diff like this), as both just result in text in `master` that is absent from `branch`.

Comment: SnoringFrog, you may be right, but the algorithm wouldn't be too difficult.  Git would have to calculate the difference between all changes on `branch` and the changes that actually resulted from their merge into `master` while ignoring all new changes on `master`.

Comment: Maybe this would be more difficult to implement than I first thought.

Comment: @DerekMahar My best initial thought (which requires more scripting work than I can do right now) is to take all the lines starting with "-" in the diff, store them, then search for each in `branch`. Anything found was removed from master, anything not found was added to master. You'd have to work with how to reformat and search for the lines effectively. Order would have to be considered though, otherwise repeated lines would create numerous issues.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the algorithm to which I referred in my [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107158/derek-mahar):

1. Calculate all changes on `branch` since it branched from `master`
   using command `git diff $(git merge-base master branch)^ branch`.  In the given example, `$(git merge-base master branch)^` refers to the parent of the first commit on `branch`.
2. Apply these changes to `master` by piping them into `patch -p1`.
3. Calculate the difference using `git diff`.

For example:

```
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ git diff $(git merge-base master branch)^ branch | patch -p1
patching file a.txt
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1 with fuzz 1.
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$ git diff
diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
index f773e76..de87c33 100644
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 Line 1 from master.
+Line 2 from branch.
 Line 2 from master.
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/test$
```

Though this doesn't omit the changes applied to `master`, it does prevent `git diff` from reporting them as changes.

**Note that step 1 would work only for cases where a branch is merged only once, which is not my case.**  Instead, we could tag the original branch commit, which fortunately, I have done.

Comment: This approach doesn't work so well when the branch has been merged numerous times with many conflicts. :(